# Read Multiple Byte Arrays from File

Tags: c#, arrays

How can I read multiple byte arrays from a file?  These byte arrays are images and have the potential to be large.

This is how I'm adding them to the file:

```
 using (var stream = new FileStream(tempFile, FileMode.Append))
      {
        //convertedImage = one byte array
        stream.Write(convertedImage, 0, convertedImage.Length);
      }
```

So, now they're in `tempFile` and I don't know how to retrieve them as individual arrays.  Ideally, I'd like to get them as an `IEnumerable<byte[]>`.  Is there a way to split these, maybe?

Comment: You can't retrieve them, you don't know how many bytes to read.  You'll have to fix the writing code and at a minimum write convertedImage.Length first.

Comment: How would you know where to split? There seems to be no information about that available in file itself.

Comment: @HansPassant...that's what I was afraid of.  Where do I split?  Can you elaborate on your second sentence, please?  If I can manually set the bytes to read for each image, that's doable.

Comment: @Evk...any ideas on how to a something to split on?

Comment: Well you got 3 answers already. Base idea is simple: first write length of image, then image itself. Repeat for all images. When reading: read length, read specified number of bytes. Repeat until file ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve multiple sets of byte arrays, you will need to know the length when reading. The easiest way to do this (if you can change the writing code) is to add a length value:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(tempFile, FileMode.Append))
{
    //convertedImage = one byte array
    // All ints are 4-bytes
    stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(convertedImage.Length), 0, 4);
    // now, we can write the buffer
    stream.Write(convertedImage, 0, convertedImage.Length);
}
```

Reading the data is then

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(tempFile, FileMode.Open))
{
    // loop until we can't read any more
    while (true)
    {
        byte[] convertedImage;
        // All ints are 4-bytes
        int size;
        byte[] sizeBytes = new byte[4];
        // Read size
        int numRead = stream.Read(sizeBytes, 0, 4);
        if (numRead <= 0) {
            break;
        }
        // Convert to int
        size = BitConverter.ToInt32(sizeBytes, 0);
        // Allocate the buffer
        convertedImage = new byte[size];
        stream.Read(convertedImage, 0, size);
        // Do what you will with the array
        listOfArrays.Add(convertedImage);
    } // end while
}
```

If all saved images are the same size, then you can eliminate the first read and write call from each, and hard-code `size` to the size of the arrays.

Comment: Looks promising, but reading the data is really slow, as in minutes, on a 750kb file.

Comment: Can you tell how many arrays are in that file? Also, if you look in task manager while it's running, what's the disk usage? How about the CPU usage?

Comment: There are 7 arrays/images.  CPU is 35% on that process (45% overall) and 0% on disk.

Comment: Now I'm confused. Are you sure it's in that part of the code that it is hanging/slowing? If not, try wrapping the section it with `Debug.WriteLine()` calls to see how long this part takes.

Comment: I'm positive.  The "size" variable is always 0.

Comment: It will run infinitely, because size always == 0

Comment: Have you confirmed that the size is written to the file? (save a file with 1 image, then view it as hex to see if the size was written correctly) (see https://superuser.com/questions/468456/how-can-i-view-the-binary-contents-of-a-file-natively-in-windows-7-is-it-possi)

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I was away for 2 weeks. The file size doesn't appear to be written to the file.  I expect it will be on the first row and humanly readable.  I'm using Hex Editor Neo to view the file as hex.

Comment: I must be in the file because the first iteration of the 'while' loop is reading it.  Problem is that it keeps on looping because an error is never thrown.  This is on a single page image file.

Comment: It's not human readable, it's binary. Try using my update, Apparently the stream does not throw a exception when it reaches the end, it returns 0 for the number of bytes read. I added this.

Comment: That's what I did already and it worked. I was hoping for a different way to break the loop, but this is okay.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you can work out the number of bytes taken by each individual array from the content of these bytes themselves, you need to store the number of images and their individual lengths into the file.

There are many ways to do it: you could write lengths of the individual arrays preceding each byte array, or you could write a "header" describing the rest of the content before writing the "payload" data to the file.

Header may look as follows:

```
Byte offset    Description
-----------  -------------------
0000...0003 - Number of files, N
0004...000C - Length of file 1
000D...0014 - Length of file 2
...
XXXX...XXXX - Length of file N
XXXX...XXXX - Content of file 1
XXXX...XXXX - Content of file 2
...
XXXX...XXXX - Content of file N
```

You can use [`BitConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) methods to produce byte arrays to be written to the header, or you could use [`BinaryWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

When you read back how do you get the number of bytes per image/byte array to read?

You will need to store the length too (i.e. first 4 bytes = encoded 32 bit int byte count, followed by the data bytes.)

To read back, read the first four bytes, un-encode it back to an int, and then read that number of bytes, repeat until eof.